How to Automate Visual Studio 2019 Using DTE and PowerShell: Call Rejected by Callee Error
I want to learn Visual Studio Automation using DTE (Development Tools Environment). I have heard that Visual Studio exposes a COM-based automation model called DTE. I want to use this with PowerShell to automate Visual Studio tasks. I have Visual Studio Professional 2019 installed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe

I have manually done the below in an elevated cmd:
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{656D8328-93F5-41a7-A48C-B42858161F29}" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Microsoft Visual Studio DTE Object" /f

reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{656D8328-93F5-41a7-A48C-B42858161F29}\InprocServer32" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /f

Here is my project folder/file structure:
|   ex001.ps1
|
+---minimal-csharp-vs2019
|   |   Program.cs
|   |   SimpleCSharpProgram.csproj
|   |   SimpleCSharpProgram.sln
|   |   ... other files

You can clone the minimal-csharp-vs2019 from here.
And here is the PowerShell script:
# Close any existing instances of Visual Studio
Get-Process -Name devenv -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force

# Add a delay to ensure proper initialization
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

try {
    # Create a new DTE object
    $dte = New-Object -ComObject VisualStudio.DTE.16.0

    # Check if the DTE object is created successfully
    if ($dte -eq $null) {
        Write-Error "Failed to create DTE object."
        exit
    }

    # Make Visual Studio visible
    $dte.MainWindow.Visible = $true

    # Resolve the relative path to an absolute path
    $solutionPath = Resolve-Path -Path ".\minimal-csharp-vs2019\SimpleCSharpProgram.sln"
    $solutionPath = $solutionPath.ToString()

    # Output the resolved path for verification
    Write-Output "Resolved solution path: $solutionPath"

    # Check if the solution file exists
    if (Test-Path $solutionPath) {
        Write-Output "Solution file found at $solutionPath"
    } else {
        Write-Error "Solution file not found at $solutionPath"
        exit
    }

    # Open the solution
    $dte.Solution.Open($solutionPath)

    # Build the solution
    $dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build()

    # Close Visual Studio
    $dte.Quit()
} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
}

When I run the PowerShell script, I get the following error:
Resolved solution path: <path\to>\minimal-csharp-vs2019\SimpleCSharpProgram.sln
Solution file found at <path\to>\minimal-csharp-vs2019\SimpleCSharpProgram.sln
<path\to>\ex001.ps1 : An error occurred: Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
At line:1 char:1
+ .\ex001.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ex001.ps1

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. For those end up here, I have developed a simple PowerShell script that might help.
